# RBAC in Node.js

Tags: node.js, access-control, rbac

I am just starting with Node.js and Express and I am a bit confused on how the get the access controls I want.

What I have are 3 user types:

- Admin
- Provider
- General

The admin and general I can do, the problem is that providers can only access one "article" while an "article" can have multiple providers. Is there an easy way to get this functionality?

Edit: User 'X' can only access article 1 and users 'Y' & 'Z' can both access article 2.

Comment: Can you describe your scenario more? Is it such that there are two articles A, B. A's owner is X, B's owner is Y. Only X should be able to see A, But should not be able to see A (and vice-versa) ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [rbac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rbac) this will work as an  authorization library for NodeJS